# What does "should" mean in this sample sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> According to the principle of judicial independence, judges should be free to make decisions based on the law without threat of negative consequences should their decisions be unpopular.

What does "should" mean in the sentence above? Is there any other word available to replace it?

Comment: ***should*** implies what *ought* to happen (the *recommended* course), whereas ***must*** implies *necessity, obligation*. But you'd get pretty close to the sense of the existing text if you substituted ***must, if possible*** (or ***ought to*** or ***will, ideally*** or similar).

Comment: It is saying that according to this principle, judges **ought to** be free to ....etc. The idea is that judges ought not to be placed under political, career or financial pressures to act in a way that other (powerful) people might wish.

Comment: I think shuo ge is referring to the second 'should'.

Comment: [correction: What does "should" mean in this sentence.]

Comment: Which *should*? I voted to close this question as it lacks clarity.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the 2nd 'should', then you can use 'if', 'in case', 'just in case', 'in the event', or 'in the circumstance that'.

https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/in_case.html

If we use those suggested terms, however, the copula 'be' has to be changed to 'are' in this example.